# Android compilation error after upgrading to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0'

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services

I am upgrading my play-services-ads library from version 12 to version 18.1:

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0'
}
```

The problem is that the compilation fails with this error:

> .gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-ads-identifier-17.0.0.aar/75b3c9fbdc51199269673bd2fa8b6cfe/jars/classes.jar(com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'GuardedBy': class file for javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy not found

I took away all the usages for AdvertisingIdClient and left only the import, but the problem persists:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient;
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: The class mentioned in the error (`javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy`) does not seem to exist in the Android SDK. There are other versions of that class, [such as `androidx.annotation.GuardedBy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/GuardedBy). Based on [this old bug report](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/707), try adding `implementation "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2"` to your dependencies, and see if that helps.

Comment: It works! Now I am wondering how... @CommonsWare could you please explain what is going on?

Comment: The AAR for `play-services-basement` includes a `proguard.txt` that specifies:
`-dontwarn javax.annotation.**`

That should allow your app to ProGuard successfully whether or not you include a dependency that includes `javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy`

Can you say what exact gradle task is failing?

Also, what version of Android Studio, gradle, and `com.android.tools.build:gradle` are you using?

Comment: @ jkasnicki - classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

Comment: @jkasnicki Task :mpsrv:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED.

Comment: I can't repro with a fresh project adding the dependency and import. Is it possible to get a minimal reproducing project, for example on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0` depends upon `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0`, among other libraries.

Your error indicates that `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0` references `javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy`. However, that class is not in the Android SDK. The POM file for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0` should be referencing a library that has an implementation of that class, but it does not seem to.

One library that has an implementation of that class is `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305`. Adding a dependency on `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305` for a recent version (e.g., 3.0.2) gave you that class, satisfying the compiler.

So, there appears to be a bug in the Play Services SDK packaging, which my workaround resolves. You might want to add a comment in your module's `build.gradle` file to consider removing the `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305` if a future update to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` fixes this bug.